# Explain laser stability and interferograms relationship

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, interference, interferometry

I am using a Twyman-Green interferometer to record phase-stepped interferograms. The interferometer uses a monochromatic diode laser (visible light). As you observe the interferogram on the screen, you often notice that the laser intensity often times goes up or drops down for a split second. For the purpose of analyzing the laser stability, I have recorded a short video (~75 fps), where I put the camera directly after the collimator lens and let it record for 100s.

My two questions are:

1: Can I extract some useful information on the laser stability from said recording?

2: How does the laser stability influence the recorded interferograms?

As a phase-stepped interferogram can be written down in terms of the average intensity I', the fringe modulation I'' and the phase step $\Delta$, how does the laser stability influence the aforementioned parameters? The formula for the n-th recorded interferogram is provided below:

$$ I_n(x,y) = I'(x,y) + I''(x,y)cos[{\phi}(x,y)+n\Delta]$$

Comment: There's no link to the video as I write this, so I can't be sure, but ...  probably no effect. Intensity doesn't affect the interferogram.   The glitches might possibly come with a small wavelength shift, but the shift would be small, and serve mostly to blur the image.  The surface features would be otherwise unaffected.

Comment: Yes, I haven't provided a link to the recording, however, there is no need for. I have an 8 bit camera, therefore the pixels can have values between [0, 255]. What I observe in the recording is that all pixel values have a median, let's say 125, and oscillate between say [123, 127]. My question was whether this change can actually influence my measurements of the wavefront in any noticeable way. But based on your answer, I would say - probably not. I also would like to mention that this small variation may very well come from sources such as the electronic noise in the camera or stray light.